# why we use $this__("Some text") instead simple echo magento

Tags: magento

I am working with magento and have a question in mind that why we use $this__("Some text") instead simple echo magento. can anyone ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call

`echo $this->__("some text");`

You can start by looking at `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`

```
/**
 * Translate
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $expr = new Mage_Core_Model_Translate_Expr(array_shift($args), $this->_getModuleName());
    array_unshift($args, $expr);
    return Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate($args);
}
```

Next is `Mage_Core_Model_App`

```
/**
 * Retrieve translate object
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Translate
 */
public function getTranslator()
{
    if (!$this->_translator) {
        $this->_translator = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    }
    return $this->_translator;
}
```

Which is handed to `Mage_Core_Model_Translate`

```
/**
 * Translate
 *
 * @param   array $args
 * @return  string
 */
public function translate($args)
{
    $text = array_shift($args);

    if (is_string($text) && ''==$text
        || is_null($text)
        || is_bool($text) && false===$text
        || is_object($text) && ''==$text->getText()) {
        return '';
    }
    if ($text instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Translate_Expr) {
        $code = $text->getCode(self::SCOPE_SEPARATOR);
        $module = $text->getModule();
        $text = $text->getText();
        $translated = $this->_getTranslatedString($text, $code);
    }
    else {
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['theme'])) {
            $module = 'frontend/default/'.$_REQUEST['theme'];
        } else {
            $module = 'frontend/default/default';
        }
        $code = $module.self::SCOPE_SEPARATOR.$text;
        $translated = $this->_getTranslatedString($text, $code);
    }

    //array_unshift($args, $translated);
    //$result = @call_user_func_array('sprintf', $args);

    $result = @vsprintf($translated, $args);
    if ($result === false) {
        $result = $translated;
    }

    if ($this->_translateInline && $this->getTranslateInline()) {
        if (strpos($result, '{{{')===false || strpos($result, '}}}')===false || strpos($result, '}}{{')===false) {
            $result = '{{{'.$result.'}}{{'.$translated.'}}{{'.$text.'}}{{'.$module.'}}}';
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

which returns the resulting text. This is a quick walkthrough of how everything would be handled, you should view the classes themselves to get a more in-depth understanding.

> In simple when you call `echo $this->__('some text')` it look up same
>   text in CSV file which is located in
>
> `app>locale`
>
> or
>
> `app>design>frontend>YOUR_PACKAGE>YOUR_THEME_NAME>locale>translate.csv`
>
> file if the same word exist then it translate a word
>
> ***means it is very useful in multi-language website***

Comment: Really nice explanation!  How do you know to start looking in Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract?  thanks again.

Comment: @KeyurShah, What happens if the text is not available in the translate.csv file? I guess in that case the text is just echoed as it is then? Correct?

Answer (score 1):

`$this->__("Some text")`

Used for translation purpose

Comment: What type of trnslation ?

Comment: Instead of mucking around, editing templates, you can update what Magento uses in displayed text by editing a simple CSV file. For all you out there that butcher templates because you don't like the text within `$this__("Some text")`, you're doing it wrong.