# PHP: What does __('Some text') do? what we can use in jquery for this same functionality?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

```
echo __("some text"); // in php
```

If we change the text using jquery that text also dynamically translate the langauge.So What we use for this `__()` instead for `jQuery`.I want method  __() in php like in  js file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why we use $this\_\_("Some text") instead simple echo magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788357/why-we-use-this-some-text-instead-simple-echo-magento)

Comment: For example if anyone follow my account the button changes the text "Following" using onclick function in js file.The Follow text is translated other language when i click the button the following text is in english only visible if i refresh the page that text is tanslated but i want to translate dynamically

Comment: @priya what you are asking seems too broad to me. It would be better if you post relevant codes.

Answer (score 3):

See, you need to understand this:

1. PHP is serverside language.
2. javascript/jQuery is clientside works on browser.

---

So, that means if you get any response from server that is already written on the server then if you act like page refresh that still persists.

While if you do changes with js/jQuery that is temporary and that gets to it's default state if you refresh the page.

More info for [__method](http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/function-__.html) cakephp method.

---

So, in my opinion you should do this serverside, which is better.

Answer (score 0):

The [`__()` method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#global-functions) in CakePHP handles localisations of text. So any text strings wrapped in this method can be easily translated by generating a POT file using the `cake` console.

This is a CakePHP PHP method so is not available on the client-side, so if you want to achieve something similar in JavaScript you will need to either use an appropriate I18n plugin or write your own method.

I personally define something similar to the `__()` method in my JavaScript so that things are kept consistent:-

```
function __(str) {
    if (typeof(i18n) != 'undefined' && i18n[str]) {
        return i18n[str];
    }
    return str;
}
```

Then I define `i18n` in my JavaScript as an array of strings and replacements for the current language (serving the correct translation array for the current locale):-

```
var i18n = {
    'translate me': 'Translated text'
};
```

To keep things nice and tidy I define the JavaScript array as a CakePHP generated page (delivered as JS) and set the translated texts using CakePHP's `__()` method. This way when generating POT files via `cake` you get translations for both client and server side.